# How exactly does the mini batch method work?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation

I mean let's say I have a mini batch, I take an example from it and for it I do the following:

1. I do forward propagation.
2. Using the output after forward propogation - I calculate the gradients of the parameters.

Then I take the next example from the mini-batch and repeat steps 1 and 2 for it, and after I get the parameter gradients I sum them with the gradients I got earlier.
After these actions are performed for all elements of the mini-batch, I use the resulting sum of gradients to find the average value of the gradients and use it to update the weights?
Am I correct?

Comment: No, you don't compute example by example. All examples of the minibatch are computed together, in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Your description looks conceptually correct to me. See [Hugh's answer to: How does minibatch gradient descent update the weights for each example in a batch?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/266977/354273) on Cross Validated for a detailed explanation.

However, as per @noe's comment, in practice mini-batches are not implemented by processing the examples one at a time. To speed up processing, most deep learning frameworks will implement this using matrix or tensor operations and process the entire mini-batch in one pass.